# Disable web page while making background process

Tags: jquery, css, jsp, html

I have default values on the database that will be check every time any user go to home page (   I don't know if this is the proper place to check, if no please correct me. ) What I want to do is:

1. Check the database if empty ( if no ignore 2 and 3 )
2. Disable the whole page
3. Fill the default values of the database
4. If done enable the page

What I want to know from the list is **number 1 ( if I check on the right place )**, **number 2 ( I don't know what should I do here )** and **number 4 ( I don't know how to disable the page well of course I don't know how to enable it )**

Comment: If you need to disable all pages on your application, consider using a filter.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you did just say. Can you tell me a bit more detail to it or a link will also do.

Comment: What I tried to say is that if you want to run a verification before you process every request, you could use a filter. Here's an example: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_writing_filters.htm

Comment: Beware of CSS tricks for hiding the content. They do not disable, just hide. Anyone half-skilled can bypass that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your questions:
1. Can't say it's not right but there are obviously better ways. I'd check that only ONCE on login and use session to store the value [database exist true/false].
2. Depending on what you mean by disable whole page. Not visible or not clickable. Either way you can assign a class name to the div and use jquery to toggle, quite easy.
3. Again, this could be done only once when login.
4. If you do this right you can enable this in your jquery expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
       var h = $(document).height();
       $("body").append("<div id='overlay'></div>");

       $("#overlay")
         .height(h)
         .css({
              'opacity' : 0.4,
               position': 'absolute',   
               'top': 0,
               'left': 0, 
               'background-color': 'grey',
                'width': '100%',
               });
    });
```

When you want to enable again your page, you just have to delete this div element by remove child

Answer (score 0):

I believe that while you are doing you background process you can disable the website by using jQuery BlockUI http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/ or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand you correctly, but you can check with php at start of your file and then accordingly display whatever you want / modify database. There is no need for disabling the page since your "background proccess" may happen on server when assembling the website on server, if I understand you correctly. Try explaining your problem more.

Pseudocode example:

```
<?php 
if($category == "home"){

  << check for database if empty >>
  if($empty == false)
    <<  fill default values of db  >>

  << display page >>
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you seen any `php` tag to above question?

Comment: It seemed to me as if OP might have been unaware of server-side solution (which doesnt rely on client-side technologies such as jquery) due to his undetailed explanation of problem. Sorry if I caused any trouble.